# How to test the argument passed in the object creation by new operator

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking

I want to test the argument passed in the constructor, e.g.:

```
class A {
  public void function (String arg1, String arg2) {
    C c = new C(arg1, arg2);
    //....
  }
}
```

In this, I want to test the `arg1` value which is being passed while creating object of class `C`. Is there a way of doing this without using PowerMock?

Comment: What do you mean "test"? Do you mean "validate"? If so, what does that have to do with "mock"?

Comment: You can say it as validation but basically I need to write Junit test case for checking that argument. So, I was thinking of a way to mock the object creation and use argumentCaptor to get the parameter.

Comment: Not following. JUnit is for exercising your code and checking for correctness, i.e. "if I call with *this*, make sure result/effect is *that*". *You* write the test cases, e.g. `new A().function("abc", "xyz")` and verify it had the expected effect.

Comment: Why do this instead of redesigning your code to be more testable, e.g. by injecting a `CFactory` or the like?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I guess I will redesign it to make use of factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, without *some* kind of mocking framework, unless you are either returning the result of the newed object (either here or in a factory), or storing it in a field for later reference, you cannot directly test that those values are passed to that constructor.  If there is something that *indirectly* makes use of that instance, you have a chance of testing it *there*, but that greatly dilutes the point of the test.

That being said, this is a very strange use case.  If you're newing an object and not doing anything with it, what's the point of creating the new instance in the first place?  The design and code flow of this particular piece of code should be called in question when sitting down to write tests like this.

If you really want to keep it around, move its creation to its own function, where you can independently test it.  You would essentially be creating a factory which would allow you to supply new instances of `C` wherever you needed it.

Comment: I actually dint wanted to redesign it because that's what the client asks for but I guess I don't have an option. Thanks for the suggestion